# GitHub and VS 2012 synchronization

Tags: github, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to sync my solutions of VS 2012 to directly merge with the repositories in GITHUB?
Like if I made a solution or project in VS 2012 will i be able to directly update it into a repository from VS 2012?Is there a additional plugin  available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution just surfing on the web.The [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeplex/archive/2013/01/30/using-visual-studio-git-with-codeplex.aspx) is here.Little details have been given below.

**The Only issue is its for CodePlex not for GITHUB**

> Brian Harry made two major announcements today at the ALM Summit.
>    1.Visual Studio will support Git
>    2.Team Foundation Server will host Git repositories.   When we added Git to CodePlex back in March of last year a missing piece, for many
>   customers, was having great Git tooling within Visual Studio.   With
>   the CTP release of Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 plus the CTP of the Git
>   VSIX you can now use Git within Visual Studio. The CodePlex team has
>   been dogfooding the tools for the last few months and we look forward
>   to getting public feedback.   Using VS Git with CodePlex   Since the
>   Visual Studio Git client works with any Git remote you can easily
>   configure it for your CodePlex Git projects.